# PowerBI-add filter based on time

Tags: powerbi

My datasource is SQL. There is a column which contains date/time when the event occurred. In PowerBI, I would like to show a graph on a weekly basis as to how many events happened that week? Would appreciate help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can easily get a chart with dates in X axis and a `Count of eventID` measure in `Values` pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with any kind of date-data you should always include a date-table that contains additional data for each day.

The table could look like [day, month-number, year-number, quarter-number, week-number, year-month, year-quarter, year-week, weekday, holidayYN, ...]. The year-month or year-week columns look like 2017-01, 2017-02, etc so you can get continuous time series tables and plots when you work with dates rangin e.g. from November to the following February (so it gets sorted A-Z which would be 2016-11, 2016-12, 2017-01, 2017-02 instead of 01, 02, 11, 12). You can either create it in Excel and import it directly or use the data transformation features in the PowerBI-query pane.

This table then gets linked to the [date]-column in your PowerBI-data model.

Whenever you now want to display, lets say, daily sales data summed up by each week you create a table/plot with the sales-values and the [year-week] column from your dates-table.